# How to create a folder in Java?

Tags: java, directory, create-directory

How can I create an empty folder in Java?

Comment: Hmm.. I Googled and this was the first result (;

Comment: @CoolBeans The creators of StackOverflow have said they want questions here to be the first hit on Google. Nothing wrong with creating a simple google-able question here if it is clearly stated and original (not a duplicate on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
File f = new File("C:\\TEST");
try{
    if(f.mkdir()) { 
        System.out.println("Directory Created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Directory is not created");
    }
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Just wondering: What case would trigger the else-branch? Wouldn't there be an exception whenever the creation fails?

Comment: Isn't it `mkdir` (all lower case)? @0xA3: mkdir throws SecurityExceptions, but surely that won't happen if C:\TEST doesn't exist?

Comment: @OxA3 If you don't have right to create the directory, the else branch is executed.

Comment: There's also `mkdirs` which will create parent folders too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()

Comment: Please don't use `catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace()}`: https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns#catchingException

Answer (score 21):

Call [`File.mkdir`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29), like this:

```
new File(path).mkdir();
```

Answer (score 20):

With Java 7 and newer you can use the static [Files.createDirectory()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectory%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) method of the [`java.nio.file.Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class along with [`Paths.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.net.URI-).

```
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("/path/to/folder"));
```

The method [Files.createDirectories()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29) also creates parent directories if these do not exist.

Comment: `Files.createDirectories()` will also silently ignore already existing directories.

Comment: @gronostaj This is only valid for parent directories. If the main directory (in this case "folder") already exists, it will thrown an exception (see also javadoc).

Answer (score 6):

Use [`mkdir()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir()):

```
new File('/path/to/folder').mkdir();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the mkdir method on the File class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29

Answer (score 4):

Using Java 8:

```
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/path/to/folder"));
```

Same:

```
new File("/path/to/folder").mkdirs();
```

Or

```
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("/path/to/folder"));
```

Same:

```
new File("/path/to/folder").mkdir();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `mkdirs` as:

```
new File("dirPath/").mkdirs();
```

`mkdirs`: also create parent directories if these do not exist.

ps: don't forget the ending `/` that shows explicitly you want to make a directory.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would be helpful for the creation of single or multiple directories:

```
import java.io.File;

public class CreateSingleOrMultipleDirectory{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//To create single directory
        File file = new File("D:\\Test");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (file.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Folder/Directory is created successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory/Folder creation failed!!!");
            }
        }
//To create multiple directories
        File files = new File("D:\\Test1\\Test2\\Test3");
        if (!files.exists()) {
            if (files.mkdirs()) {
                System.out.println("Multiple directories are created successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to create multiple directories!!!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can follow the link also:  https://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-create-directory.shtml