# Creating file with empty title

Tags: java, file

I tried creating a file with empty title or just a space and it worked but I cannot find the file in the directory. I could not even delete or rename file.

```
File dir1 = new File("dir1");
dir1.mkdir();
File file1 = new File(dir1, "");
file1.createNewFile();
```

`System.out.println(file1.exists());` always returns true even if I execute `file1.delete()` or `file1.renameTo(...)`

Comment: *"I tried creating a file with empty title"* Why?!?

Comment: You need to give absolute path here new File("C:\\dir\\file.txt"); or new file("/usr/loc/file.txt");

Comment: A file must have a non-empty name. I'm assuming that in your case `file1` is referring to your directory `dir1`.

Comment: I've found some previous questions on Stack Overflow:

Show [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java

Comment: @JoeTaras That question is irrelevant to this one.

Comment: It is impossible to create a file without name, even space is forbidden for that, you must use any character, you can not use / or < in the name of the file. File1 appears because you search if exists anyfile without name and extension. Really it dosent created.

Comment: @Nima: I linked that question, about creation of folder (first part of this question)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I tried this out just to see if it works (might be helpful for interviews/exams too :-)).

Comment: @Deckard27 I actually don't see any compilation error while running this piece of code. It says file exists. Just need to know if that file is actually present and if you can access it or not?

Comment: *"might be helpful for interviews/exams too"*  I very much doubt it.

Comment: The "dired" mode in Emacs is very handy for deleting files with impossible names. Note that much of the discussion above is incorrect: certainly most Unix systems do, indeed, let you create files with names like this.

Comment: Thanks @ErnestFriedman-Hill. I'm trying this on Windows and it lets me create files with empty string names.

Comment: Enerst but in window yo can not to create a file without name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are passing an empty string for the child, Then the `file1` will be the same as `dir1`, anything you're doing to `file1` is actually happening to the directory you just created.

Here is a sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

File directory = new File("/home/test");
directory.mkdir();

File file = new File(directory, "");

System.out.println(file.exists());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(directory.getAbsolutePath());

file.delete();
System.out.println(directory.exists());
System.out.println(file.exists());  
}
```

**output:**

```
true
/home/test
/home/test
false
false
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer for AbsolutePath. But, when you do a `file.delete()`, it still does not delete the file or the directory. `..exists()` still gives true. Please check

Comment: Strange, on my machine with jdk 7 it does delete the folder and return false afterwards..

Comment: Depends perhaps of the Os that you are using, i think that in unix is possible, but not in window.

Comment: Hmmm. I was using just jre. I installed jdk and this supposedly worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I think it used eclipse's own compiler which would not have supported this.