# Create folder structure using java code

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I need to create a folder structure using java code.
I have tried this:

new File("G:\a\b\c").mkdirs();

But how can I make files inside "a" folder or create another tree structure like "G:\a\m\k".
I basically need to create a complete project structure just like eclipse does using "New Wizard".

Comment: Read [How to create a folder in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java) and [How to create a directory in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634853/how-to-create-a-directory-in-java) that might help you.

Comment: call it again `new File("G:\a\m\k").mkdirs();` to create another directory.

Comment: Calling it again worked,but how can I make .java files inside those folders?

Comment: Do you want to create a file in a folder? Read [How to create a file in a directory in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142901/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-directory-in-java) and search on Google first.

Comment: yes, my main moto is to create a project structure programmatically.

Comment: So where is issue? Please post the code where you stuck.