# How to proceed with making an in - BlueJ Java file manager

Tags: java, bluej

I know that it is a bit of a noob program, but I'm slowly getting confused. The 'down' function is going to act like cd and the 'up' function would act like cd..

I have no clue how to allow the user to create a file or folder. I attempted using arrayLists instead of arrays but couldn't sort out the errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class FileManager {
    //array of arrays will go here
    String Dir[] = {"UserOne"};
    String SystemFolders [] = {"Documents","","",};
    String SubFiles [] = {"","","","","",""};
    String Nav [][] = { Dir, SystemFolders, SubFiles};
    int levelCounter = 0;
    public void main(String[]args)   {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a command");
        String command = sc.next();
            if (command.compareTo("down") == 0)
                down();
            //else if is on the way
    }
    void down ()    {
        //This will execute when the command is 'down'
        System.out.println(Nav[++levelCounter]);
    }
    void up ()  {
        //This will execute when the command is 'up'. It acts like cd..
        System.out.println(Nav[--levelCounter]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the entry point of your program then you need to declare your `main` method as static, like so

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Then to access the methods in your `FileManager` class in your main method you need to create an instance of your class in your main method. Like this

```
public static void main(String[]args)   {
    FileManager fm = new FileManager();  // Creates an instance
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a command");
    String command = sc.next();
    if (command.equals("down")) // equals will suffice in this case
                                // or equalsIgnoreCase() if you dont want case to be a problem
        fm.down(); // Notice now this calls the down method from the instance
    //else if is on the way
}
```

Then look at this to example to [create files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java) or this to [create folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java)