# Can not create file in specific directory in Java (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: java, file, java-io

I have code that can create file in D disk in my Computer an can write some information in this file.Here is source

```
File file = new File("D:\\" + filename);
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true); 
writer.write(builder.toString());
writer.close();
System.out.println("done!");
statusText.setText("Information successfully saved!");
statusText.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
```

This code working correct but when i try to change file directory like this i have exception

```
File file = new File("D:\\testFolder\\" + filename);
```

Here is a exception

```
IOException: D:\testFolder\2017-08-11.csv (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

What am i doing wrong or how i can solve my problem?

Comment: But.... do you have a ***"testFolder"***???

Comment: no ,i have not.I want to check if exist  @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ

Comment: how to create a directory is a different question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Creating Directory first:

```
            String filename = "myfile";
            File file= null;

//          Check if directory exists
            File directory = new File("D:\\testFolder\\");
            if (directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory()) {
                //create your file
                file =  new File(directory +"\\"+ filename); 
            } else {
                // Create directory
                directory = new File("C:\\testFolder\\");

                if(directory.mkdir()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory Created");
                    file =  new File(directory +"\\"+ filename); 

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Directory is not created");
                }

                // Create file
            }

            FileWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
                writer.write(builder.toString());
                writer.close();
                System.out.println("done!");
                statusText.setText("Information successfully saved!");
                statusText.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks your attention .How i can create some file inside this File directory if exist? @mohit sharma

Comment: @Beka Check it now ,

Comment: I tried it but my testfolder is empty @ mohit sharma

Comment: @Let me run it here

Comment: This is correct code file = new File(directory +"\\"+ filename);
That was error  @ mohit sharma

Comment: @Beka Thanks for acknowledging i'll update in the answer

Comment: Very poor code. Repetitive and redundant. `mkdirs()` is all that is needed. The existence and directory check and the repeated file creation are just a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 2):

you can not do that if that folder doesnt exist...
you will just get an java.io.FileNotFoundException

create the folder firts

```
File dir = new File("C:\\" + "__folder");
dir.mkdir();
```

or

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

depending on how deep the parent/child folders go

Comment: Thanks,but i know how to check if file exist.But I would check like this.If directory exist (D:testfolder for example) create some file inside this directory ,else create new folder and then create new file  @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ