# Create folder and print to text file from command

Tags: java, file-io, filewriter

For example you have a command where the second argument is a directory plus file name:

```
String fileName = "createF dir/text.txt";
String textToFile="apples, oranges";
```

How can I create **"dir/text.txt"**, a folder called dir, a txtfile and write the contents of **textToFile** to it?

The issue is it is a command. And it is file name can be changed to another file name. I can't  use `FileWriter` method. It gives  no directory error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a folder in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024002/how-to-create-a-folder-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't get a clue of what you're trying to say. Please add some more information and include your existing code. **For more help take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using java 7 or above you can try java.nio.file package. Example code:

```
try {
    String fileName = "createF dir/text.txt";
    String textToFile="apples, oranges";

    String directoryPath = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(" ")+1, fileName.lastIndexOf('/'));
    String filePath = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf(" ")+1, fileName.length());
    Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(directoryPath));
    Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), textToFile.getBytes());
}
catch (IOException e){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String fileName = "createF dir\\text.txt"; 
    String textToFile="apples, oranges";

    String splitter[] = fileName.split(" ");

    String actualPath = splitter[1];

    File file = new File(actualPath);
    if (file.getParentFile().mkdir()) {
        file.createNewFile();
        new FileOutputStream(actualPath).write(textToFile.getBytes());
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Failed " + file.getParent());
    }
}
```